# Apt-get repeatedly failing. Authentication warnings and 404 errors

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, cifs

I'm a bit out of my depth here and I need some advice.  I'm trying to adapt an SMS gateway to output to a network location.  It runs on Voyage Linux.

I'm attempting to install the cifs-utils package in order to access a Windows network location, but getting nowhere.  In fact, all apt-get commands seem to be returning errors.  Here is an example when I run update:

```
root@foxbox:/# sudo apt-get update
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-it
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-it
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-it
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free i386 Packages
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-it
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-it
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-it
Hit http://www.voyage.hk ./ Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze Release
Ign http://www.voyage.hk/dists/0.8/ ./ Translation-en
Ign http://www.voyage.hk/dists/0.8/ ./ Translation-it
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/contrib i386 Packages
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://www.voyage.hk ./ Release
Err http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/main i386 Packages
404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/contrib i386 Packages
404  Not Found
Ign http://www.voyage.hk ./ Packages
Err http://ftp.jp.debian.org squeeze/non-free i386 Packages
404  Not Found
Hit http://www.voyage.hk ./ Packages
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404 Not Found    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/contrib/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/non free/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any/all advice is appreciated.  I've been given this project but I'm having to learn my way around Linux as I go; I only have a rudimentary understanding.

Comment: some repos don't have the paskages you're looking for anymore. Does it prevent you from doing the install ? If so, try to find working repos

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old debian so repositories doesn't exist anymore.
You have to fix the repository file, look for /etc/apt/sources.list

make a backup of this file :

```
cp -p /etc/apt/sources.list /root/sources.list
```

then replace the content with appropriate url, packages are here now

http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian-6.0/

Comment: Thanks for the help!

It's progressed to this stage, after trying to install cifs-utils:

    `Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Package cifs-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

    E: Package 'cifs-utils' has no installation candidate`

Is this a factor of squeeze being an old distribution with a reference to a location for cifs-utils that doesn't work anymore?

Comment: use : "apt-cache search cifs" to find the package name, it seems it's not cifs-utils anymore.